# Confused about a closures in Javascript and global variables

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, closures

I understand that `var` cause a single binding for an `i` in a loop.

Can somebody explain why the answer is 5?
Does `i++` increments one more time on a function call?

Try to debug it, but still confused about workings of a loop.

```
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  result[i] = function(){
    return i;
  }
}
console.log(result[0]())
```

Comment: *"In the example below, I understand that since loop is in the global scope, variable `i` is saved and remembered due to closures."* Yes, but it's a global and all functions share it, because you've used `var`. Variables declared with `var` are scoped to the containing function (if there were one) or global scope (in your example). That one `i` is closed over by all functions created in the loop, so they all see the value of `i` as it was at the **end** of the loop (`5`). ...

Comment: ... If you used `let` (`for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i)`), there would be a different `i` for the block for each loop iteration, the functions would each close over their own `i`, and you'd see the output you expect (`0` from `result[0]`, `1` from `result[1]`, etc.).